# electron: app's icon resolution goes down compared to after having run electron-builder

Tags: npm, electron, electron-builder

[image]

I'm building an electron app, and the above image on the left is how my icon looks in the app when i'm testing it with electron and on the right is after I've compiled it into an executable using "yarn dist".
(these are screenshots of them from my windows bar at the bottom of the screen).

It seems like the resolution of the icon in the executable is worse than in the raw electron app. The file itself is quite high resolution:[image]

The icon is called during development by the "main.js" file:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  // frame: false,
  title: "Collector: Kitten " + app.getVersion(),
  icon: __dirname + "/logos/collector.png",  //<--- This line
  webPreferences: {
    //contextIsolation:           true, //has to be false with the way I've designed this
    enableRemoteModule:         true,
    preload:                    path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true
  }
})
```

And is identified by the builder in the package.json "win":

```
"build":{
  "win": {
    "target": "nsis",
    "icon": "logos/collector.png"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent this loss in resolution when using the electron-builder?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by converting the .png into a .ico file and using that instead.

Comment: what was the size?